# How to Store data as Object in Flutter please

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

**my code outputs are the X and Y each time u touch the app what i want is to save All my Xs and Ys in a table of objects and send that table to server as json form**

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:prefs/prefs.dart';
//import 'dart:async';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => print('tapped!'),
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => _onTapDown(details),
      onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) => _onTapUp(details),
    );
  }

  _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    var y = details.globalPosition.dy;
    //  var response;
   
    // or user the local position method to get the offset
    print(details.localPosition);
    print("tap down " + x.toString() + ", " + y.toString());
    // log("${response?.statusCode} :  ${response?.request?.path}",
        //  name: "Response", error: response.data);
  }

  _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    var y = details.globalPosition.dy;
   // var response;
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object` like this:

```
Map<String, double> coordinates = { "x": details.globalPosition.dx, 
                                    "y": details.globalPosition.dy }
```

Then you need to convert it into `JSON` format. Make sure you converted the object into a `String` like following:

```
json.encode(coordinates.toString());
```

Comment: i cant send this data to server django

Comment: please haw i can store this data on json file